# If Google deletes my extension, is it still installed on the computers?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

For example, I have 100 users with my extension, but Google deletes my extension, is it still installed on the computers?

Comment: As evidenced by the Stylish extension controversy, they can tell Chrome to disable it locally too, but not to remove.

Comment: I wonder, is the extension automatically disabled from computers or is it still enabled?

Comment: It was automatically disabled and a notice about it being taken down in the web store was shown on chrome://extensions page.